# [iOS]How can I omit protocols?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, protocols

I'm newbie of iOS

I'm trying to make a simple browsers using UIWebView.

This is my Code.

"ViewController.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addrInputField;

-(IBAction)enterButton:(id)sender;

/*go back btn*/
-(IBAction)goBackBtn:(id)sender;

/*go front btn*/
-(IBAction)goForwardBtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

"ViewController.m"

```
/*url enter button*/
-(IBAction)enterButton:(id)sender{

    NSString *str = [_addrInputField text];
    NSURLRequest *rqst = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
    [_webView loadRequest:rqst];
}
/*go back button*/
-(IBAction)goBackBtn:(id)sender{
    if([self.webView canGoBack]){
        [self.webView goBack];
    }
}
/*go forward button*/
-(IBAction)goForwardBtn:(id)sender{
    if([self.webView canGoForward]){
        [self.webView goForward];
    }

}
```

This simple things are all of my code.

Input url in Text Field and touch enterButton then webView is changed.

When I input url in textField like : "http://apple.com", then view is changed.

But input url : "apple.com", view didn't work.

how can I omit the protocol when I input urls?

p.s I wonder how to handling both http and https.

Thanks for reading.

******Add details.

[image: input url in chrome before press ENTER Button]

when I pressed Enter..

[image: After Enter Button Pressed]

The Chrome modify my inputs "apple.com" to "https://apple.com" automatically adding protocol "https://".

I want adding this function in my Apps. Thanks.

Comment: you mean that the user wouldn't have to enter `http` or `https`?

Comment: That's right. That is my problem.

Comment: What do you want when user don't enter `http` or `https`. Still acess the site or search it with google?

Comment: I will edit my post and add detail things.

Comment: I have a news for you. Chrome use WKWebView instead of UIWebView. Good luck :D.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the string from your textfield, after creating `NSURL`, you can retrieve `URLScheme` from it. If it's `nil`, you can add `http` yourself.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
if url.scheme == nil {
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",str];
   url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
}
```

Comment: `http` mostly auto redirects to `https`